# Calculating APR

Tags: c#, math, financial

So, as the title says I need to calculate the APR for a loan. I have the following:

```
apr = (rate * ((Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration))) /
      ((Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration)) - 1)) -
      (installment / (loanamount - extracost));
```

But its not returning the correct value. I also tried another version of that equation with even worse results:

```
apr = ((loanamount + extracost) * rate * Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate),duration) - 1);
```

The calculations are all wrong. I tried adjusting some parenthesis and checking the order of operations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you provide the 'mathematical' formula you are trying to implement?

Comment: is this the formula you are trying to implement? 
`(P0 * r * (1+r)^n)/((1+r)^n - 1)`

Comment: Yes Buck, that's the formula I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it sounds like cheating, but I just used the existing VB financial library .NET has. Its for annuities so you have to make the payment a negative number.

Term is full number of payments(i.e. 15 year mortgage has 180 payments so 180)
Payment is payment per (so monthly payment amt... x -1)
Starting Amount = original loan amount with no fees

```
  double apr = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.Rate(term,-payment,originalLoanAmt)
```

Then just multiply by the answer by the annual # of payments (if monthly then 12) or if you want the % expressed as a number like 3.25%, then multiply by 100 as well.

**note you have to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

Comment: what is the payment, it is not very clear how you would get it.

Comment: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial does not exist in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly!

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating the payment amount given *duration* as the number of payments.  That's not the APR. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
double apr, loanamount = 3000d, extracost = 7000d, rate = 0.05;
int duration = 1;
apr = ((loanamount + extracost) * rate * Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate),duration) - 1);
Console.WriteLine(apr);
duration = 2;
apr = ((loanamount + extracost) * rate * Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate),duration) - 1);
Console.WriteLine(apr);
duration = 3;
apr = ((loanamount + extracost) * rate * Math.Pow((1 + rate), duration)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate),duration) - 1);
Console.WriteLine(apr);
```

where the output is

```
10500
5378.0487804878
3672.08564631245
```

Only the first answer is the same as what you might expect from A=Pe^(rt) or similar calculations of the amount from the principal.
The actual calculation you need depends on both the legal jurisdiction and the type of credit/loan though.